# Why doesn't an Interface contain properties

Tags: c#, interface

I am looking to implement an Email library that send out a basic SMTP email with `To`, `From`, and `Message`. I want to create an `Interface` so that I can switch out the Email service that handles sending the mail.

My question has to do with creating the interface. Since whatever concrete class that handles sending the message will need some data like `To`, `From`, and `Message`, shouldn't the Interface have these properties also?

In looking at other examples on SO and in other articles it seems that properties are not usually specified in the `Interface`. Why is that?

```
// Interface
public Interface ISendMail
{
  string to {get; set;}
  string from {get; set;}
  string message {get; set;}
  bool SendMessage();
}
```

as opposed to this ...

```
// Interface
public Interface ISendMail
{
  bool SendMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> it seems that properties are not usually specified in the Interface

That's wrong. There are plenty interfaces that have properties. Take the interop interfaces for Office addins for example. They are loaded with it.

There is even an entire topic on it on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64syzecx.aspx).

Comment: Correct, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64syzecx.aspx

Comment: Whoops, must be my "getting close to 5pm color blindness" that made me miss the link @Pat!

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces in C# can contain properties. From the section 1.9 of the [C# Language Specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) (emphasis is mine):

> An interface defines a contract that can be implemented by classes and structs. **An interface can contain methods, properties, events, and indexers.** An interface does not provide implementations of the members it defines—it merely specifies the members that must be supplied by classes or structs that implement the interface.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly fine to have properties in an interface. I consider them as methods (should be lightweight though).
For example:

`string Message { get; set; }`

is equivalent to declaring these two methods

```
string GetMessage();
void SetMessage(string value);
```

And to add, without auto-implemented properties, you still need to have corresponding fields for your getters and setters.